# How to Get a Return Value of a Java Class in UNIX

Tags: java, shell, unix

Please suggest a way to get the return String from my class in UNIX.

This is my sample class:

```
package com.mytest.package.main;

    public class DateExtractor {

        public static String getDate() {
          return "20120924";
        }

        public static void main (String[] args) {
           system.out.println(getDate());
        }

    }
```

And my UNIX script:

```
JAVA_BIN="/usr/bin"
log_dir="/usr/tmp/log"
JVM_OPTION="-Xms512m -Xmx2g -DprojectName=mytestproj -Dlog.dir=$log_dir"
CP="/usr/tmp"
MAIN_CLASS=com.mytest.package.main.DateExtractor

$NOHUP $JAVA_BIN/java ${JVM_OPTION:-} -classpath $CP $MAIN_CLASS
```

Expected Result:

```
echo $Data_from_getDate
20120924
```

Comment: getDate is doing a return. it's not doing output. `System.out.println(getDate())`?

Comment: i have updated... please suggest a way... !!

Comment: The problem I think you're having is that Java will only ever return a "exit value" back to the calling process.  As MarcB has pointed out, you program as it stands doesn't generate any output.

Comment: You must first compile Java (.java) to machine code that the JVM can read (.class) in order to run a Java application.  I assume you haven't compiled your program because your code will not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two recommendations:

Put the output of your program on the standard output

```
System.out.println(getDate());
```

To echo the result in your unix script

```
echo `$JAVA_BIN/java ${JVM_OPTION:-} -classpath $CP $MAIN_CLASS`
```

Answer (score 2):

Use : `SimpleDateFormat`, There are a lot date format

[DateFormat Example](http://www.javablogging.com/java-simpledateformat-examples/)

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    String dateAsString = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
    System.out.println(dateAsString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return int code from program (usually 0 means success and anything else is error) and get it in $? shell variable - but not string. Use println and `your-program-here-` in shell to get output.

Comment: damn.. that was backquote characters, don't know how to make it displayed correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a string, UNIX programs have an integer return value (that you can specify with `System.exit(value)`.

Everything you print in Java goes on standard output and is usually printed on the terminal.

You can store the output in a variable with

```
Data_from_getDate=$( $NOHUP $JAVA_BIN/java ${JVM_OPTION:-} -classpath $CP $MAIN_CLASS )
echo $Data_from_getDate
```